# How do I compile drivers / kernel modules for use in Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, module, driver, kernel-module

Just to expand with some examples, here is the problem:
Given the following source:

```
/* hello.c */

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world\n");
return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world\n");
}

/* end of hello.c */
```

and the following Makefile:

```
obj-m += hello.o
all:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

When I type make while in the same directory as the source and make files, I get the message: 'Nothing to be done for `all'
The compilation seems to stop here and no object file is created.

Now just for testing, I tried a new simpler Makefile:
    TARGET  := hello
    ${TARGET}.o: ${TARGET}.c

Running make gives me the new error:hello.c:1:    fatal error: linux/module.h: No such file or directory.

however this file IS available in the folder:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-22/include/linux
```

and also in

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-22-generic/include/linux
```

as is the kernel.h file

What am I missing, any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will at least need the kernel source, to get the required header files...

Comment: NB: The full source however is not needed; the build environment (this includes Makefiles, Kconfigs, scripts/, and .h files in certain dirs) suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the lines beginning with 'make' in your Makefile are indented by a tab character.
That is the line below 'all:' and the line below 'clean:' should begin with a tab.